# conditionally counting number of values in a nested python json dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json response object 
and i want to count the number of occurrences of state=`healthy`

```
d= {
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "content-length": "444", 
            "content-type": "text/xml", 
            "date": "Tue, 12 Nov 2019 02:30:11 GMT", 
            "x-amzn-requestid": "1234"
        }, 
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200, 
        "RequestId": "1234", 
        "RetryAttempts": 0
    }, 
    "TargetHealthDescriptions": [
        {
            "HealthCheckPort": "80", 
            "Target": {
                "Id": "i-dummy", 
                "Port": 80
            }, 
            "TargetHealth": {
                "State": "healthy"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "HealthCheckPort": "80", 
            "Target": {
                "Id": "i-testing", 
                "Port": 80
            }, 
            "TargetHealth": {
                "State": "healthy"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried:

```
count = 0
for x,y in d.items():
    if y['State'] == 'healthy':
        count += 1
print(count)
```

but it complains

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deploy_staging_web.py", line , in <module>
    if y['State'] == 'healthy':
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

How do I get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
def get_sum(d):
  val = 0 if not isinstance(d, dict) else d.get('State') == 'healthy'
  return val+sum(get_sum(i) for i in getattr(d, 'values', lambda :d)() if isinstance(i, (dict, list)))

print(get_sum(d))
```

Output:

```
2
```